# Do normal modes need same amplitude?

Tags: waves, normal-modes

Suppose we have a coupled pendulum of 2 masses.

I understand that the first normal mode they oscillate together, *in phase*, with the same frequency. However, do they need to have the same amplitudes?

Suppose we describe the motion of both masses as

$$ x_1 = A\cos(\omega t) $$
$$ x_2 = B\cos(\omega t) $$

Since they both have the same $\omega$ and they are in phase. It is necessary that $A=B$? Can they not have different amplitudes but still the same frequency?

Comment: The relative amplitudes are fixed for each normal mode. For the case of both pendula the same, but coupled by a spring, then one normal mode has $A=B$ and the other has $A = -B$. To answer more fully we would need to know what your level is: do you know how to write and solve differential equations?